# Show textfield in other div when radio checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, I've gone through lot of sources but I've got confused applying them all. I'm new to javascript and jquery.
I have a step by step choices (i got a wizard template). So I wanted to display a **text field** from the previous step/div when "wedding" radio button is checked.

my html code:

```html
<div id="step-1"> 
  <fieldset> 
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="wedding" onchange="see()" />
    <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="bday" onchange="see()" />
    <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cake_theme" value="occassion" onchange="see()" /> 
  </fieldset> 
</div>

<div id="step-2">
  Date: <input type="date" name="date_pick"/> //remains
  <div class="wed_delivery"> Venue : <input type="text" name="wed_delivery" placeholder="Venue to Delivery"/> //only shows up when "wedding button" is checked 
  </div> 
</div>   
<div id="themedisplay" height="100px" width="300px"> </div>
```

I have in my JS in different file: (working fine)

```js
function see(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake');
  if (document.getElementById('theme1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Wedding Cake";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('theme2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Birthday Cake";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('theme3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Occassion Cake";
  }
}
```

I tried putting below the div "step-1"

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".wed_delivery").hide();
  $("#theme1").click(function () { //theme1 is the Wedding Theme
    $(".wed_delivery").show();
  }); 
</script>
```

It doesn't work, is it possible in a Wizard Template? 
Thanks in advance, comments each line are appreciated.

Comment: just remove the `$(document).ready` function. Rather put it into a function. Because `$(document).ready` only works on page load.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you., I'll try to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you. Point to note.

1: Close your document.ready function properly.

2: Include JQuery if not included.

3: Bind the event with radio buttons and hide/show the text box if the checked radio is/is not wedding radio button

```js
function see(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycake');
 if (document.getElementById('theme1').checked) {
        document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Wedding Cake";}

    if (document.getElementById('theme2').checked) {
        document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Birthday Cake";}

    if (document.getElementById('theme3').checked) {
        document.getElementById('themedisplay').innerHTML = "Occassion Cake";}
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step-1"> 
    <fieldset> 
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="wedding" onchange="see()" />
    <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="bday" onchange="see()" />
    <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cake_theme" value="occassion" onchange="see()" /> </fieldset> </div>

    <div id="step-2">
    Date: <input type="date" name="date_pick"/> //remains
    <div class="wed_delivery"> Venue : <input type="text" name="wed_delivery" placeholder="Venue to Delivery"/> //only shows up when "wedding button" is checked </div> 
</div>   
    <div id="themedisplay" height="100px" width="300px"> </div>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".wed_delivery").hide();
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function () { //theme1 is the Wedding Theme
       
        if($(this).val() == "wedding")
          {
             $(".wed_delivery").show();
           }
      else
        {
           $(".wed_delivery").hide();
          }
    }); 
     });
</script>
```

Comment: wow that's pretty helpful, thank you! Can I just apply the script in my html ? Or in other js file?

Comment: @ScottRookie Both works fine but i will recommend to keep the scripts ina separate for better management and neat html.

Answer (score 1):

Establish 2 classes to represent the status of off and on and assign the textbox the `.off` class initially. When the `change` event is triggered, then use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` jQuery methods.

There are too many changes to OP to explain, so I commented details in the Snippet:

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() { */
$(function() {
  /* change event triggered by any radio button */
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    /* $(this) is the function owner, 
    |  in this case it is the specific 
    |  radio button being changed 
    */
    // Get radio value
    var title = $(this).val();
    // Get radio data-img
    var img = $(this).data('img');
    // Get url of background-image
    var path = 'http://imgh.us/' + img;
    // Set text of figcaption
    $('#themeTitle').text(title);
    // Set background-image of figure
    $('#themeDisplay').css('background', 'url(' + path + ')no-repeat');
    // if the checked radio id is 'theme1'...
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme1') {
      //...status of textbox is on...
      $('.wedDelivery').addClass('on').removeClass('off');
    } else {
      //...otherwise status of textbox is off
      $('.wedDelivery').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.off {
  display: none;
}
.on {
  display: inline-block;
}
#themeDisplay {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#themeTitle {
  font: 700 16px/1.4 cursive;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset id='step1'>
  <legend>Event Themes</legend>
   <!--data-img represents the image file name can be manipulated by .attr() or .data()-->
  <label>Wedding
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cakeTheme" value="Wedding" data-img='wedcake.jpg'>
  </label>
  <label>Birthday
    <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cakeTheme" value="Birthday" data-img='bdaycake.jpg'>
  </label>
  <label>Special Occasion
    <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cakeTheme" value="Special Occasion" data-img='speccake.jpg'>
  </label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="step2">
  <legend>Pick-up/Delivery</legend>
  <label>Date:
    <input type="date" name="datePick">
  </label>
  <label class='wedDelivery off'>Venue :
    <input type="text" name="wedDelivery" placeholder="Venue to Delivery">
  </label>
</fieldset>
<figure id="themeDisplay">
  <figcaption id='themeTitle'></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Wow, neat! Thank you for the comments each line that really helps me alot!! For the JS script you include. Should I put it in another **new JS file** ? or In my existing js file where I display the cake?

Comment: oh, nevermind I manage it to put in the html. It's working so fine! Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome, sir. Either way works. My personal preference is if it's about over 80 lines of code, I'll use an external JS file, and anything smaller I usually place in a `<script>` block and place it before the closing `</body>` tag.